# Fitting the size of folium.DivIcon to the content

Tags: html, folium

I wonder whether it's possible for `DivIcon` to have a dynamic size.

The context:
On my map, hovering over a country will trigger a tooltip with the country's name.
I also have several `DivIcons`, with the following code:

```
folium.Marker(
    location=[lat, lon],
    icon=folium.DivIcon(
        html='''
            <div style="background-color: red; display: inline-block;">
                <span>
                    {region_name}:
                    <br />{region_info}
                </span>
            </div>
        ''',
        icon_size=(100, 100),
        icon_anchor=(0, 0),  
    )
).add_to(map)
```

Because of the variation in `region_name`s and `region_info`s, the width of the content varies between 50 and 90 pixels. I want my text to be displayed on two lines and the `div` to fit its content: the `display: inline-block` property in the html allows me to do this, even if my `icon_size` is constant.

But the problem is that the size of the `DivIcon` affects the tooltips: I can have a 70px-wide block with content, but an area of 30px next to it which doesn't display as a block but still counts as that block. So if I hover out of the visible block, instead of the tooltip appearing with some country's name, nothing happens. This is especially problematic when this area covers a bunch of small countries.

What I'd like to happen is for the `DivIcon` to fit to the html within, or to have some kind of dynamic behaviour. I have tried doing `icon_size=(10, 10)` or removing `icon_size`, but the block just shrinks to fit to the longest word in the content. I have tried to go through the code for `folium.DivIcon` and up the inheritance tree (`branca.MacroElement`, `branca.Figure`, etc.), but wasn't able to get control of this behaviour.

Any suggestions welcome.